# 8 speed shimano claris cassette on Campagnolo Calima C17

Tags: wheels, cassette, speed

I'm looking to replace my two wheels and I've been recommended this [Campagnolo Calima C17 Clincher Road Wheelset](https://www.merlincycles.com/campagnolo-calima-c17-clincher-road-wheelset-113227.html).

I currently have a [Shimano Claris 8 speed cassette](https://www.bike-discount.de/en/buy/shimano-claris-8-speed-cassette-cs-hg50-8-11-32-160135).

The wheels are described as 10/11 speed. From my reading around I think an 8 speed Shimano cassette should fit and 8/9/10 speed wheel with no problem. And I'd need a spacer for an 11 speed. Is this correct and if so how do I figure out what spacer I need? Thanks

Comment: It's best to name the components you are dealing with explicitly and not rely on the links as the pages you linked to may disappear. I've edited you question for you.

Answer (score 3):

A road 11 speed compatible wheelset will have a freehub body that is 36.75mm wide. A 8/9/10 speed compatible wheelset will have a freehub body that is 34.95mm wide - 1.8mm narrower.

You can fit 8, 9 and 10 speed cassettes on an 11 speed freehub body with the addition of a 1.8mm spacer.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct about the cassette compatibility. If you are already shopping online, the easiest way is to do a web search for Shimano cassette spacer and pick one that adapts 8-10 speeds to 11-speed road freehub. It is possible that the wheelset already comes with such a spacer, so it is probably best to ask the seller first.